# Why does Showing a UserForm as Modal Stop Code Execution?

Tags: vba, modal-dialog, userform

The following VBA code stops at `Me.Show`. From my tests, it seems that `Me.Show` stops all code execution, even if the code is inside the UserForm.

*This part is outside the UserForm*:

```
Public Sub TestProgress()  
    Dim objProgress As New UserForm1
    objProgress.ShowProgress
    Unload objProgress
End Sub
```

*This part is inside the UserForm*:

```
Private Sub ShowProgress()
    Me.Show vbModal
    Dim intSecond As Integer
    For intSecond = 1 To 5
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = intSecond / 5 * 100
    Next intSecond
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

The code stops at `Me.Show`, after the UserForm is displayed. There is no error, it just discontinues executing code. It seems that the only way to execute code inside a modal UserForm in VBA is to include it in the UserForm_Activate procedure like this:

*This part is outside the UserForm*:

```
Public Sub TestProgress()  
    Dim objProgress As New UserForm1
    Load objProgress
    Unload objProgress
End Sub
```

*This part is inside the UserForm*:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Show vbModal
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim intSecond As Integer
    For intSecond = 1 To 5
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = intSecond / 5 * 100
    Next intSecond
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Of course, I can't put `Me.Show` inside UserForm_Activate because that procedure only fires after the UserForm Show event.

The documentation for `UserForm.ShowModal` says "*When a UserForm is modal, the user must supply information or close the UserForm before using any other part of the application. No subsequent code is executed until the UserForm is hidden or unloaded.*"

I am trying to use a modal UseForm as a progress bar to prevent the user from interacting with the application while a process runs. But this will be difficult to accomplish if all my code has to be within the UserForm_Activate procedure.

Am I missing something here? Why does all code execution stop at `Me.Show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out.

After `Me.Show` the UserForm_Activate event fires. If there is no code in the UserForm_Activate procedure nothing will happen because VBA is waiting for `Me.Hide`.

So the order of events is: `Me.Show` > `UserForm_Activate` > `Me.Hide`

Any code that I want to run must be in the UserForm_Activate procedure and must be *before* `Me.Hide`.

The structure is very strict, but I may be able to use that structure to my advantage.

Comment: All that you really need to do if you want to still be able to interact with the sheet while the form is up is use this code when calling the userform: `userform.show vbModeless`.

Answer (score 12):

When the form is displayed with `vbModal`, the code will suspend execution and wait for user interaction with the form.  For example clicking a button or using a dropdown.

If you update the form property

```
ShowModal = False
```

and remove `vbModal` from your code.  This will allow code execution to continue when the form is displayed.

Comment: Yup, vbModeless UserForms are easy, but I need to lock out user interaction with the application until the process finishes. It was just a matter of figuring out how to structure the code in a vbModal UserForm. Too bad the documentation doesn't just say "if you use vbModal make sure to put any code you want executed in UserForm_Activate and _before_ Me.Hide. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't work for me. The calling `sub` does continue running, but absolutely no components are rendered, not a even a simple label.

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for an answer to why I was getting the following error:

> Run time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

when running this line of code:

```
UserForm1.Show True
```

even though this line works:

```
UserForm1.Show False
```

Of course. **True** is not the same as **vbModal**! So the simple answer is to use the correct enumerations:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModal
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```