# Event Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick provides values from previous double-click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of people with work to assign to:

[image: Table to edit]

I want to use the `BeforeDoubleClick` Event to invoke a form showing all the relevant fields, so that the user can consult/correct the fields.

The form looks like this:

[image: Work form]

In the corresponding worksheet, I have the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("tblTime")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
    
        frmAssignNewWork.Show
    
        frmAssignNewWork.Controls("cboPerson").value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).value
        frmAssignNewWork.Controls("cboWork").value = Cells(Target.Row, 4).value
        frmAssignNewWork.Controls("txtStartDate").value = Cells(Target.Row, 5).value
        frmAssignNewWork.Controls("txtEndDate").value = Cells(Target.Row, 6).value
        frmAssignNewWork.Controls("txtFocus").value = Cells(Target.Row, 7).value * 100
```

It works somewhat, as it shows the form, and populated fields in the right place, BUT it populates the form with the fields that were selected on the PREVIOUS double-click.

To clarify, if I double-click a first time, the form will appear with blank fields.
Then, if I double-click a second time on the same cell, it will display the correct information of that row in the correct fields.

However, if I double-click a third time on a different row, it will display the information of the former row, etc.

I would think it has to do something with the concept of "Before" double-click, but if I insert a check such as:

> MsgBox (Target.Address)

It does always provide the correct address...

Anyone can help out there? :)

Comment: Put `MsgBox "!"` right after the `frmAssignNewWork.Show`. That will hopefully explain it.

Comment: Try to move `frmAssignNewWork.Show` to the end of the procedure

Comment: Thank you Алексей Р, this worked!I would have assumed that setting the value of the fields on the form would refresh them, but apparently not :). I also believed wrongly that I had to show the form before being able to update the fields

Comment: @MoonLunatic Yes it does refresh them. It didn't for you because that code does not run [until you close the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1784410/11683) in the first place, which you would have seen if you had put [the `MsgBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259325/event-worksheet-beforedoubleclick-provides-values-from-previous-double-click#comment120638746_68259325). Otherwise it's perfectly possible to change values on an already shown form.

Answer (score 0):

Move frmAssignNewWork.Show to the end of the procedure solved it